# SQL Server - What role to use for application access?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

What Server Role(s) and/or Database Role(s) must a SQL Login have to do the following:

1. Read Data (including Temp tables)
2. Write Data (including Temp tables)
3. Execute any SP within a database which they are granted access

We are migrating from SQL 2000 to 2008 and I'm going through all the Logins and have noticed they are all set to sysadmin & db_owner, which isn't good.  Our apps that use these logins will only do what I've listed above so that's why I'm wondering.  I know I can set each Login with a Database Role of db_datareader & db_datawriter but that doesn't include executing SP's.  We've got close to 300 SP's in 2 or our DB's and to have to go through each SP and set the login permissions in the Extended Properties would be WAY too long and tedious.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would either just deal with it and set the permissions manually or (my preference) create database roles that have the types of permissions you want to give, and assign logins to those. That way if multiple logins need the same set of permissions, you just give them the same role.

As a bonus, if your programmability objects have some sort of prefix naming convention so that (for example) procedures that read from your login information tables all start with something like pAccount_ or something, then you can dynamically do `GRANT`s to roles based on the prefix of the routine.

Comment: I went this route as it gives me the most flexibility for my current situation.  Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 1):

> to have to go through each SP and set the login permissions in the Extended Properties would be WAY too long and tedious

And yet, this would also be the most secure.

Using the built in roles exposes too much of your database to your application.

Comment: Yes, most secure but how do you manage all your SP's and permissions with the regards to logins?  We don't have a DB Admin here, it's just me (another guy who left recently)...

Answer (score 1):

Can you give the `db_datareader` and/or `db_datawriter` execute rights? This will give the user rights to execute any stored procedures in databases it has access to. If you have views you will also need to grant them select rights.

```
GRANT EXECUTE TO db_datawriter
```

Comment: I guess 'Alter' wouldn't be needed then, seeing as how these apps are not "altering" any tables.....does that include deleting temp tables?